# Alembic is creating tables in the postgres/public schema instead of the public schema of the database in the connectionstring

Tags: postgresql, alembic

I'm automating the migration of some tenant databases. I have one set of credentials and I'm replacing the database name into the connection string. However, alembic is creating tables in the `postgres/public` database/schema, presumably as that's the default database for the credentials I have.

My connection string looks like

```
CS=postgresql://username:password@postgres.example.com/some_tenant
```

my alembic command looks like

```
alembic -x sqlalchemy.url='$CS' upgrade xxyyzz123
```

Is it possible to get alembic to honour the database specified in the connection string?

Ideally I don't want to include an environment in the alembic.ini for each tenant. The script I'm writing lists all tenant databases on the server (by a name prefix) and calls alembic with that database name appended to the connection string.

Comment: A quick search found this [Run Multiple Alembic Environments](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/cookbook.html#run-multiple-alembic-environments-from-one-ini-file). Would that work?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver yeah, I saw that and forgot to detail that in the question. If I can avoid having to add an entry for each tenant that would be preferable.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with Alembic to offer an alternative. Hopefully someone more knowledgeable comes along with an answer or you could try over here [Alembic discussions](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/alembic/discussions/).